# Fine E(4X^2+4X+1)

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

So I have the following tables

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{c|ccc}
      x&-3&6&9\\
      f(x)&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I am tasked to find the following values

E(X), E(X<sup>2</sup>),E(4X<sup>2</sup> + 4X + 1)

For E(X) I got 5.5

For E(X<sup>2</sup>) I got 46.5

And for E(4x<sup>2</sup>+4x+1) I got 61

Are these values correct? They seem sort of high to me,

Thanks
John

Comment: Looks much too low.

Comment: $(2X+1)^2$ takes values $25, 169, 361$ with probabilities $1/6,1/2,1/3$. Now calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Linearity of expectation, we have $$\mathbb{E}[4X^2+4X+1] = 4\mathbb{E}[X^2]+4\mathbb{E}[X]+1.$$

If you plug in $\mathbb{E}[X] = 5.5$, $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 46.5$, and $\mathbb{E}[4X^2+4X+1] = 61$, the left side of the above equation is $61$, but the right side is $4 \cdot 46.5 + 4 \cdot 5.5 + 1 = 209$. So you have a mistake somewhere.

I'll go ahead and tell you that your answers for $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ are correct: $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \dfrac{1}{6} \cdot -3 + \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 6 + \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot 9 = 5.5$$ $$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \dfrac{1}{6} \cdot (-3)^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 6^2 + \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot 9^2 = 46.5$$

So you should double check your calculations on the last part.

Comment: Duh, math is hard when you're tired lol

Answer (score 0):

The first and second look good, but the third can't be right.

Since expectation is linear in its argument ($E(aX + b) = aE(X) + b$),

$$ E(4X^2 + 4X + 1) = 4E(X^2) + 4E(X) + 1 = 4(46.5) + 4(5.5) + 1 = 209. $$

(You should double check this by calculating the third expectation directly again.)